# Do physical and digital Dead by Daylight for PS4 share the same savefile?

Tags: ps4, dead-by-daylight

So I have a PS4 disc game and it’s *Dead by Daylight*. I want to go digital so I can save all of my progression when I have to buy a newer console. Can I sell my disc copy and buy digital DbD and save my progression?
If so, does it do it automatically when I finish downloading the digital copy or do I have to do something to save it myself?

Sorry if this doesn’t make sense, just a causal gamer trying to save my progress.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/98v3sh/do_digital_copies_of_games_use_the_same_save_data/), **yes**:

> As long as the region matches, the save data should work.

Users can confirm this works with games like *Battlefield 4* and *Horizon Zero Dawn*, so it should be the same with your *Dead by Daylight*.

Also, for your second question:

> To make sure the game saves carries over, I copied the save file to a USB to be safe, deleted the application game data, then downloaded the digital version. **Started it up, and acted just like the install from the disc**. Didn’t even need the USB.

---

**Edit:** @childe, wondering about Behaviour account, I found [this Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/deadbydaylight/comments/e3dfo3/physical_to_digital_ps4_transfer_question/):

> DLCs and cosmetics are **bound to your account** and are digital so they should be fine, as for data it should not matter what copy do you have

and [this one](https://old.reddit.com/r/deadbydaylight/comments/94db3n/question_for_ps4_players/):

> Of course you'd keep your s**t it's **tied to your PSN not your game copy**.

> Play the digital one and **all save files an accounts are there**. User Game data and save files are separate from the actual game files.

Comment: I'm not sure this is totally accurate. DbD doesn't play by having a local save file, it plays by using a Behavior account which carries your perks, cosmetics, and progress over.

Comment: @childe if that's like Rocket League with a Psyonix profile, then I can confirm it's the same for digital and physical copy.

Comment: If your doubt is about the online data, those are bound to the account used, if the game is played by physical or digital it makes no difference. The account is the same.